# Is there a way to embed code that uses python's Networkx package for graphs on a website so that the output can be displayed directly on the website?

Tags: python, html, networkx, vs-web-site-project

I am designing a website about a research project on small-world networks. We are writing codes to visualize different graph metrics. Python has a great package for graphs called networkX, so all our code is in python. For example, this piece of code plots a graph and displays some characteristics of the graph.

```py
import sys

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from networkx import nx

G = nx.lollipop_graph(8, 3)
nx.draw(G)
plt.show()

print("radius: %d" % nx.radius(G))
print("diameter: %d" % nx.diameter(G))
print("eccentricity: %s" % nx.eccentricity(G))
print("center: %s" % nx.center(G))
print("periphery: %s" % nx.periphery(G))
print("density: %s" % nx.density(G))
```

[a plot of a lollipop graph(8,3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7fZQ.png)

My goal is to somehow include and run such snippets of codes on the website so that these plots can be displayed on my website when a user inputs what kind of graph they would like to see. Is there a way for me to embed python code in HTML?

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @above_c_level I tried to make the question more specific. I tried using trinket to embed the code, but trinket does not have the networkX package.

Answer (score -1):

You could run it with a trinket:

```html
<html>
     <head>
      <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
      <title>PY game</title>
     </head>

     <body>
      <iframe src="https://trinket.io/embed/python/b7ae19a9ca? 
      outputOnly=true&runOption=run&start=result" width="100%" height="100%" 
      frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
     </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but if you read the [ask] page, you notice that the question does not meet community guidelines. As such, it is discouraged to provide answers (which prevents deletion of the question) - having a large number of poor questions on the site makes it hard for everyone to find quality questions/answers (because of high-noise ratio)